# C Preprocessor precedence

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have the following problem:

```
extern void func_name(const char *f);  
#define EXPECT(f) func_name(#f)  
#define foo bar  

void main()  
{  
     EXPECT(foo);  
}
```

So, the

```
EXPECT(foo);
```

will be actually evaluated to

```
func_name("foo");
```

What I actually need is to convert 'foo' to 'bar', i.e. the code to become

```
func_name("bar");
```

So I kind of want to do this:

```
#define "foo" "bar"
```

But this does not work, because macro names must be identifiers. I also tried to find a way to change the preprocessor precedence, so my macro will be replaced first, but didn't find a way.

The perfect solution will not change main() at all.

Comment: I just ran into this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25331999/macro-meta-programming

Comment: If your textbook tells you that `void main()` is correct, its author has lied to you. Get a better book. The correct definition is `int main(void)`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C Preprocessor, Stringify the result of a macro](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419332/c-preprocessor-stringify-the-result-of-a-macro)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#define S(x) #x
#define EXPECT(f) func_name(S(f))
```